# CSS Background Images not loading

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image

I've got a very strange bug in chrome recently that is when you load the page first time, or in incognito mode that none of the background images show.

when you then F5 the page, the background images all load in.

When you inspect the css it shows the image url in the css panel, however when you mouse over the url it doesn't display a tool tip with a preview of the image.

Neither when you check the downloaded resources are there even any mention of the background-images downloading.

you then refresh the page and it works fine, tool-tip of the css url even shows a preview.

The bug only randomly happens on first load occasionally, no way to guarantee to reproduce this.

Also its worth to note, it you untick then retick the background-image property on chrome it then downloads and displays the image.

I've got a piece of jquery that solves the issue but as you can see its hardly very elegant!

```
$('*').each(function(){
var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
$(this).css('background-image', 'none');
$(this).css('background-image', bg);

});
```

this happens on every instance of windows in multiple versions of chrome.

any ideas would be great! thankyou!

you might be able to see it happen on http://ensa.ac.uk

here is a video demonstration @ http://youtu.be/oLTyhk5rXgE

Comment: No such bug found. Try clearing your cache by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Delete` on Chrome.

Comment: @Libin Nope, the bug exists. Though it works fine with firefox.

Comment: @Libin as I mentioned, this happens on multiple instances of computers, that have never before been cached, plus I mentioned Incognito mode that cacheless anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to note.

The problem had been solved.

The issue was that the browser downloads all the css background images last. So if you refresh the page before its finished downloading the images, when the page loads again it loads from the cache. but because the images did not fully download they dont show correctly.

Comment: It worked OK in my simple test case, but still seeing the issue in an app I'm working on. In the environment where I see this, the Chrome Dev Tools "Network" tab shows that the background image does not load even when the element containing it is made visible. It's not until I use dev tools (or your hack method) to uncheck/recheck the background-image style property that Chrome requests the image from the server. It's annoying because the jquery UI uses background image sprites, so users complain that in chrome they can't see the close "X" button in dialogs until they mouse over it.

Comment: So it's because the images were not fully loaded when on display. But how did you solve it? :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix these:

```
backg1round-color: #c7dfe3;
backg1round-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.67);
```

If images is a subfolder then use

```
url('images/logo-bg2.jpg');
```

instead of

```
url('/images/logo-bg2.jpg');
```

in main.css

Comment: images is in the root dir, so httpdocs/index.php and httpdocs/images/ however when we've got multiple levels ie site.com/category/articles/entry/ images/ doesn't suffice and we dont want to rely on a base href, its done the way it is for a reason, also the main.css is in /style/ so it needs to go up a directory anyway. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Not tested though;

```
$('*').each(function(){
var bg = $(this).css('background');
$(this).css('background', 'none');
$(this).css('background', bg);
});
```

And make relevant changes (ie, `background-image` to `background`) in your CSS also.

**OR try;**

```
$('*').each(function(){
var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
$(this).css('background-image', 'none');
$(this).css('background-image','url(bg)'); // or try url("bg") i am confused :P
});
```

From some search and research I came to a conclution;

> The way I would tackle this is with classes. Have a separate CSS classes for each of the states, then simply use jQuery to change the class. This would ensure that all of the images are actually downloaded and available when you set the class -- which is where I think Chrome is failing (probably all WebKit browsers would do this)

Comment: this most likely works, however I'd already posted this? I'm in search for a fix, not a hacky solution, especially if this runs on every page load on every page, not good at all. I'd ideally like to know WHY its happening

Comment: May be because of some chrome incompatibility with jQuery. Try different versions of jQuery, including complete and minified versions.

Comment: have this issue on several websites that all use different versions of jquery anyway, even websites that done use jquery, so jquery cant be the issue :(

Comment: various versions, all the office computers have an array of versions from Canary to nightly builds to beta and stable builds. All of them have the same issue

Comment: check the new answer. Added a few things.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, there are no states. Its just when the webpage loads, have a look at http://youtu.be/oLTyhk5rXgE and you'll see what happens

Comment: alright then. have you tried the second option, adding `url()` ?

Comment: its beside the point. i can fix it with jquery fine, infact i already have. But I want to know WHY this is happening.

Comment: I think Chrome (probably all WebKit browsers) fails to downloaded and make the images available.

Comment: but why would it? its just standard css

Comment: Just confirmed - works fine in FF/IE7-10/Safari. So not necessarily a webkit bug, just a chrome issue.

Comment: In fact I just now observed the same bug in chrome running on android (on my droid bionic... was testing on windows 7 pc previously). Your fix works great of course, but ugh.. how annoying.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change css class as:


#nav
{
    background-image: url(../images/logo-bg2.jpg);
    height: 180px;
}
```

Comment: so what happens when you load http://website.com/page/page/page/page css will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Owen,

I still see this problem on the application that I'm working on.  I know this is also a hacky solution, but it's a little less hacky than the jquery solution that you had posted. I simply threw a version number based on time after the css include and it

e.g.
    " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

I know that this causes the css to never be cached, but I have not found any other solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you edit your answer to put the HTML reference in a code block since it's otherwise not showing up correctly here?  I tried to edit it for you, but the change was so minimal (basically requiring an extra blank line between "e.g." and the code) that SO wouldn't let me save it without making a bigger change first.