# issue with jquery and updating css background images not loading in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, dom, web-inspector

I'm trying to replace a background image on an element with jquery. The code looks correct, and if i stop the execution of the page and inspect the element, it is the correct element. However, it does not show in chrome or in the element preview when hovering over an element.

I came across what appears to be the exact same issue here [CSS Background Images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227716/css-background-images-not-loading) but the fix supplied does not work.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Don't use separate images for button states. Have a sprite sheet and change the background position. This prevents image flashing when the browser realizes it needs to load a new image since this technique guarantees it has already loaded all the states in one image.

Answer (score 0):

When you change background images, the element's width and height vanish from the CSS styles.

Try adding

```
overflow: hidden;
border: none;
width: 125px;
height: 25px;
margin-top: 4px;
```

back to the CSS styles for `.products-grid li.item .select-pack-container.pleasewait,
.catalog-product-view .select-pack-container.pleasewait`

Comment: For the select-pack-container, I actually used sprites as suggested for the add to cart buttons, and that worked great. However, I tried applying the above fix to the sidebar pleasewait icon, and it didn't work. Any other clues? I updated my original post with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a second 'pleasewait' div and making it hidden by default. I then hide/remove the go div and show the pleasewait div... works fine. Still not sure what is happening on the background-image replacement in chrome. Looks like a bug to me. All the other browsers act fine.